# Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

How can I execute the following SQL inside a single command (single execution) through ADO.NET?

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
    ADD NewCol INT

GO

UPDATE [MyTable] 
    SET [NewCol] = 1
```

The batch separator `GO` is not supported, and without it the second statement fails.

Are there any solutions to this other than using multiple `command` executions?

Comment: Why would you want to add a column through ASP.NET? Does that mean that you will be adding columns indefinitely?

Comment: deploying database changes though an update mechanism?

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Answer (score 114):

The `GO` keyword is not T-SQL, but a SQL Server Management Studio artifact that allows you to separate the execution of a script file in multiple batches.I.e. when you run a T-SQL script file in SSMS, the statements are run in batches separated by the `GO` keyword. More details can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

If you read that, you'll see that sqlcmd and osql do also support `GO`.

SQL Server doesn't understand the `GO` keyword. So if you need an equivalent, you need to separate and run the batches individually on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I used this regex to get rid of GO statements before executing the command.

pattern = @"(?:\s|\r?\n)+GO(?:\s|\r?\n)+"

Answer (score 31):

Remove the `GO`:

```
String sql = "ALTER TABLE  [MyTable] ADD NewCol INT;";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql = "UPDATE [MyTable] SET [NewCol] = 1";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It seems that you can use the [`Server` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) for that. Here is an article:

[C#: Executing batch T-SQL Scripts containing GO statements](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/)

Comment: Great answer!! I suppose that it supports all the other SQLCMD mode instructions.

Answer (score 17):

In SSMS (SQL Server Management System), you can run GO after any query, but there's a catch. You can't have the semicolon and the GO on the same line. Go figure.

This works:

```
SELECT 'This Works';
GO
```

This works too:

```
SELECT 'This Too'
;
GO
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT 'This Doesn''t Work'
;GO
```

Answer (score 11):

This can also happen when your batch separator has been changed in your settings. In SSMS click on Tools --> Options and go to Query Execution/SQL Server/General to check that batch separator.

I've just had this fail with a script that didn't have CR LF line endings. Closing and reopening the script seems to prompt a fix. Just another thing to check for!

Answer (score 5):

Came across this trying to determine why my query was not working in SSRS. You don't use `GO` in SSRS, instead use semicolons between your different statements.

Comment: Two different things. Semicolons are statement terminators. Microsoft recommends you get used to adding them, just as with other DBMS (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql#transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql). `GO` is used in some clients as a batch separator. It’s not actually SQL, which is why its syntax is so different.

Answer (score 5):

I placed a semicolon `;` after the `GO`, which was the cause of my error.

Answer (score 3):

You will also get this error if you have used IF statements and closed them incorrectly.

Remember that you must use BEGIN/END if your IF statement is longer than one line.

This works:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'Row count is zero.'
```

But if you have two lines, it should look like this:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
PRINT 'Row count is zero.'
PRINT 'You should probably do something about that.'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when I placed the 'GO' keyword after a sql query in the same line, like this:

```
insert into fruits (Name) values ('Apple'); GO
```

Writing this in two separate lines run. Maybe this will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to remove `GO` statements by pattern matching on `(?:\s|\r?\n)+GO(?:\s|\r?\n)+` regex but found more issues with our SQL scripts that were not compatible for SQL Command executions.

However, thanks to [@tim-schmelter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25680847/5755313), I ended up using [`Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) package.

```
string sqlText;
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=FOO;Integrated Security=True;";
var sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
var serverConnection = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(serverConnection);

int result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText);
```