# Powershell Invoke-sqlcmd2 - Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm getting the syntax error of `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`. I tried a few methods and one of them worked. Anyone can explain it to me?

Source for invoke-sqlcmd2: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1

Worked:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -Query "SELECT 1 FROM TableA GO"
```

Didn't work:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -Query "Print 123 GO"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near 'GO'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680812/incorrect-syntax-near-go)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't need the 'GO' command.