# PHP PDO Incorrect syntax near GO, MSSQL & sql_srv

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am having trouble executing a long `MSSQL` script using `PHP` and `PDO`.

It contains some batch statements separated by `GO`. The script runs if its executed in `Management Studio`.

I have ensured line endings are not causing the issue.

I have also tried to enable `beginTransaction()` before the request is executed. Which returns the following error: `SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This function is not implemented by this driver.`

I'm using `IIS8` and `PHP 5.4.16` and the `pdo_sqlsrv` driver

First part of the script:

```
USE foo;

IF object_id(N'ToBit', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
  DROP Function dbo.ToBit

GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ToBit(
    @InputString varchar(250)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutputBit BIT
    SET @OutputBit = CASE 
                 WHEN (@InputString = 'yes') THEN 1
                 WHEN (@InputString = 'true') THEN 1
                 WHEN (@InputString = '1') THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
              END
    RETURN @OutputBit
END
```

Is it down to the driver? I can't see why `GO` would require `beginTransaction()` being called? Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Update: I think I might have found an answer here. Will update if I find a soloutio. 
[Incorrect syntax near 'GO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680812/incorrect-syntax-near-go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have found an answer here by [Jon Galloway](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way)

`GO` isnt valid `T-SQL`, its a command used by SQLCMD and other utilities, and parsed before execution.

It looks like there are a few options.

1) Execute the script using OSQL / command line

2) Split the script at each GO separator, then run them in sequence

3) If using .NET you can look at using SQL Server Management Objects:
`Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery()`

This parsers T-SQL statements and "gets" the GO statement as a batch separator.