# invoke-sqlcmd fails shows no results on certain type of queries

Tags: sql-server, powershell

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.' -Database 'MyDB' 
      -Query 'EXEC SprocA  @param1= "value";EXEC SprocB  @param1= "value";'
```

Basically I have my `Invoke-SqlCmd` running a query that invokes two stored procedures. Both the stored procedures output a bunch of rows.

However if `sprocA` does not output any results (empty select results or no rows), then the invoke command does not seem to print the output of the second `sprocB` even if it has data.

If I change the order of the stored procedures in my `Invoke-SqlCmd` commands query parameter, then this works perfectly and returns the output of the first stored procedure.

If I had three stored procedure calls where the first returns data and the second does not and the third does, it prints output of the first result and third result.

Basically it does not print any output only if the first stored procedure has no output. Seems weird.

Anything I can do to get around this SQL wise ? Could be a PowerShell thing?

I was also able to repro this with two `Select` statements where one returns data and the other does not.

Comment: In short: yes, you're seeing a (perhaps surprising) fundamental PowerShell behavior, discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4552), among others. Even though it's not obvious, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45704074/45375 is ultimately about the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is the documented behavior of [invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

> When this cmdlet is run, the first result set that the script returns
>   is displayed as a formatted table. If subsequent result sets contain
>   different column lists than the first, those result sets are not
>   displayed. If subsequent result sets after the first set have the same
>   column list, their rows are appended to the formatted table that
>   contains the rows that were returned by the first result set.

It looks like both result sets are actually returned, but not output by defaut.

EG

```
   PS C:\> Invoke-SqlCmd "select 1 a; select 2 b, 3 c;" | % { $_ | Out-Default }
```

outputs

```
a
-
1



b c
- -
2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for updating; now that we know this works, I suggest eliminating the aux. variable: `Invoke-SqlCmd "select 1 a; select 2 b, 3 c;" | % { $_ | Out-Default }`. It is not obvious, but at heart this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705068/45375. Also, I suggest adding a link to the GitHub issue where this fundamental display problem - which is not specific to `Invoke-SqlCmd` - is being discussed: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4552

Comment: I think this is a bit different. I am not talking about two queries where columns returned are different. I am talking about the third sentence in the highlighted text you pasted. "If subsequent result sets after the first set have the same column list, their rows are appended to the formatted table that contains the rows that were returned by the first result set." 

If the first result set was an empty set, then | % { $_ | Out-Default } doesn't seem to fix it.

eg. Invoke-SqlCmd "select 1 a where 1=0; select 2 b, 3 c;" | % { $_ | Out-Default } should print b c
- -
2 3  but it does not.

Comment: @mklement0  `Invoke-SqlCmd  "select 1 a where 1=0; select 2 b, 3 c;"`  is the use case I wanted to fix . `

Comment: Ok that's a different issue.  It looks like Invoke-SqlCmd stops processing resultsets when it encounters one with zero rows.  No reason it must do that, and it's inconsistent with sqlcmd.exe.  So you might try a feedback item: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server  As a workaround, you're back to SqlCommand/SqlDataReader.

Comment: foreach ($s in $scripts)
 {
       $script = $s.FullName
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $SqlDatabase -Inputfile $script -ServerInstance $SqlServer | Out-Host
 }

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is hard to believe MS made such a mistake or maybe it's not a mistake. Whatever, when you run `Invoke-SqlCmd` and with a query like the following,

```
select * from table1 where id = 1111 -- non-exists id, this select returns nothing
select * from table2 where id = 2222 -- exists id, this select returns something
```

On SSMS you can see 2 result sets, the first one is empty.

However, the `Invoke-SqlCmd` doesn't return anything when the first result set is empty, even other result sets are not. My face was like ?_?

Another approach is to write you own invoke SQL function like following to return whatever result sets, even the empty ones.

```
    $sql_Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $sql_Conn.ConnectionString = $sqlConnectionString
    $sql_Conn.Open()
    $sql_cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query, $sql_Conn)
    $sql_ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $sql_da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($sql_cmd)
    [void]$sql_da.fill($sql_ds)
    $sql_Conn.Close()
    return $sql_ds
```

Everything is fine until a new problem comes about the keyword `GO` in your script, you must know it if you use SSMS. The thing is, this `GO` is not a SQL command. it is just a separator used by SSMS. MS developed codes can handle the `GO` in a good manner, e.g. SSMS, `Invoke-SqlCmd` and `sqlcmd.exe`. If you use your own SQL invoke function you will get syntax issue

[Incorrect syntax near 'GO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680812/incorrect-syntax-near-go)

While people most likely to ask you to update the SQL script to remove all `GO` lines, however, things are not always under controlled, normally need to work with different people and teams.

At last, I have to trim the `GO` in my scripts like the following

```
$Query = $Query -ireplace "(^|\r|\n)[ \t]*\bGO\b[ \t]*(\r|\n|$)", '$1$2'
```

https://github.com/LarrysGIT/Invoke-Sql

Of course, the story is not over, the more I am trying to automate SQL related tasks. The more issue found. There are multiple ways to automatically execute SQL script. None of them are perfect so far.

`Invoke-Sql` (My own script)

```
* Is able to handle the key separator 'GO'
* Is able to handle duplicate columns
* Fully support multiple result sets, even the first result set is empty
* Unable to handle `Create or alter` keywords if there are contents ahead
* Unable to handle special characters like '194 160' (non-breaking space) in SQL script (edited by some document edit tool, MS word for example)
```

`Invoke-SqlCmd`

```
* Is able to handle the key separator 'GO'
* Is able to handle special characters like 'non-breaking space'
* Unable to handle duplicate columns
* Unable to fully handle multiple result sets (when the first table is empty)
```

`sqlcmd.exe`

```
* Is able to handle all things (briefly tested)
* The returned result sets are plain text, hard to parse
```

`Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO` snapin

```
* The API of SQL server management studio
* Theoretically should be able to handle all cases
* Need to dig more
```