# GO statement in Access ADO

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado

I'm trying to use the GO statement in a query passed to SQL Server 2017 from VBA code in MS Access 2019. The execution results in runtime error:

> 80040e14 "Incorrect syntax near GO".

Exactly the same query executed in SSMS works fine.

What am I doing wrong? It works if I remove the GO line.

In Access Module:

```
Public SQLDB As Object
Public ADOcom As Object
Public Const adCmdText as Long = 1

Sub CreateDB()
  Dim sql As String, connectionstring As String

  connectionstring = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" & _
                     "Server=MySQLServer;" & _
                     "Trusted_Connection=yes;" & _
                     "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" & _
                     "DataTypeCompatibility=80;" & _
                     "MARS Connection=True;"

  Set SQLDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set ADOcom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  SQLDB.Open connectionstring
  Set ADOcom.ActiveConnection = SQLDB
  ADOcom.CommandType = adCmdText

  sql = "USE Master;" & vbCrLf & _
        "GO" & vbCrLf & _
        "CREATE DATABASE MyTest"

  ADOcom.CommandText = sql
  ADOcom.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near 'GO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680812/incorrect-syntax-near-go)

Answer (score 2):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement, instead it is a command recognized
>   by the Sql Server Management Studio (i.e. SSMS), SQLCMD and OSQL
>   utilities.

[Reference](https://sqlhints.com/tag/go-statement-in-sql-server/)

You don't need to use GO statement in commandText

Comment: Ah, as easy as that! Thank you.